# Shifting the slides numbers from right to center

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I am using `beamer` class for preparing slides for my lecture. I have some the following codes. Howe could I shift the slides numbers from right to center? I read some similar questions that have been asked in this site, but the answers of them did not work for my file.

```
 ‎\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}‎
    ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\usetheme{metropolis}
    ‎‎‎\setbeamercovered{transparent}‎

    ‎‎‎\usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    ‎\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} ‎ ‎
    ‎\usepackage{mathtools}‎
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usefonttheme{serif}

    ‎\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{11.2}{7.2}{{Times New Roman}}}

            ‎
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
    \setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=black}
    \setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=‎\large‎}

    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]



     ‎\begin{document}
     ‎
     \begin{frame}\frametitle{Motivations and Goals}‎
     text text text

     \end{frame}‎
     ‎
     \begin{frame}\frametitle{Budget}
     Flowers
     \end{frame}‎
     ‎
     \begin{frame}\frametitle{Target Values} \label{targets}
    ‎$‎F=0.52‎$‎
     \end{frame}

     \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

- If your beamer version is reasonably new, you don't need `\usepackage{etoolbox}`
- you don't need to load `amsmath` and `amsthm`. Beamer already loads these packages.
- In the following I centred the page number. If you want to use overlays in your presentation, you might want to replace `totalpagenumber` with `totalframenumber`

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalpagenumber]%
  \usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}%
  \hfill\hspace{0pt}%
  \vskip2pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Motivations and Goals}
text text text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Budget}
Flowers
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=targets]
\frametitle{Target Values}
$F=0.52$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]